# C++ struct and array concept (-Wmissing-braces])

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

I am trying to do something like this..I have 3 header files

```
1. coordinates.h

typedef struct {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
}coordinates3D;

2.plane.h

#include "coordinates.h"
typedef struct{
    coordinates3D plane;
} plane3D;

3.pointArray.h
#include "plane.h"

plane3D points[] ={
    {1.0f,3.74f,0.2354f},
    {6.823f,9.234f,1.097f},
};
```

and a cpp file

```
4. main.cpp
#include "pointArray.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout<<points[1].plane.x;
    std::cout<<points[0].plane.y;
}
```

Everything is working fine but I get a warning message

> warning: missing braces around initializer for 'coordinates3D'
>   [-Wmissing-braces]

I am not sure how to solve this warning ...

Comment: I'm not getting any compiler warnings. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: By the way, if you're programming C++ you don't need `typedef` for structures. All structures are types so doing only `struct coordinates3D { ... };` is enough to define the type `coordinates3D`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the nested structures. Simply add a couple of braces around the values:

```
plane3D points[] ={
    { { 1.0f,3.74f,0.2354f } },
    { { 6.823f,9.234f,1.097f } },
};
```

The outermost is for the array, the next pair is for the `plane3D` structure, and the next is for the `coordinates3D` structure.

Comment: If I have to modify my plane.h to 
coordinates3D plane1;
coordinates3D plane2;
how do I place the brackets of the points array?..

Comment: @ranjan `plane3D points[] ={ { { 1.0f,3.74f,0.2354f }, { 1.0f,3.74f,0.2354f } }, ... };`